# How to remove the right launcher border?

Tags: 16.04

How to remove the launcher border?

The orange border (my background image is orange):

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you can't get rid of that 1-pixel line.

Comment: @edwinksl this is a big problem :(

Comment: My workaround is to pick a background that makes the 1-pixel line way less obvious. You can try doing that if the line really bothers you.

Comment: @edwinksl tks :)

Comment: No problem, sorry I don't have an actual solution for this.